Using telekinesis to minimize the effects of g force on the human body
Background
In my world all the superpowered characters have specialized forms of telekinesis aka control over the movement of matter. One character is a speedster who can accelerate to the speed of sound in a second using tactical telekinesis. As my story is somewhat scientific the speedster still has to deal with the side effects of such speeds.
Question
So what are some ways for this speedster to subconsciously use telekinesis to make themselves able to withstand such forces?
Constraints

The speedster can only move in a straight line.

Telekinesis can be used inside the body and it can be programmed to do certain things.

The other side effects of super speed can be ignored.

The environment is the same as modern earth

The speedster has the build of an athletic adult male.



Wikipedia says that the record holder is John Stapp who survived a deceleration from about Mach 0.9 to rest in a little over a second as part of a rocket sled deceleration experiment in 1954, with no long-term ill effects. So there is experimental proof that a well-conditioned human can take it.

vtc: science-based and super-powers don't make sense together.

@JohnDallman is that better

@Coolcats112: Yes.

"control over the movement of matter" is NOT what telekinesis means.  That's because "tele-" is (Ancient) Greek for "far off".

Equal push
Speed is not inherently damaging. We can see this from planes and rockets. Put people in a steel tube, launch them and when they're at a stable speed no one has any problems. To put it in another way, the ISS in space is going 7,66 km/s. The speed of sound is 0,343 km/s. The launch of the rocket to space was much more intense at lower speeds because of acceleration. For the body it is even more important that there is a difference in acceleration on the micro and macro scale. Your blood vessels generally accelerate faster than the blood in your vessels, causing an unequal distribution of the blood and force on where the blood is 'pushing'. Again, among a myriad of other things.
Now there is the important part. If you could accelerate the body fully equally, there is no problem. If you have someone pulled from orbit towards a star, they'll not notice the acceleration regardless of the amount of G's. It is slightly more nuanced, but the principle is the same. If you would use telekinesis to accelerate everything at once to the correct speed, you'll prevent any G force problems.
I would imagine telekinesis can be in several forms, where this can be imagined as a field that encompasses the body perfectly, maybe including a small boundary outside for clothes. It'll accelerate with the exact same speed as you're running. That will mitigate the most dangerous parts of running at such speeds. Unequal acceleration and deceleration. It'll also be more easy to imagine a field that works in tandem with the body, so you can move your body in running motions at the speeds required to run that fast.
There's the other considerations. When hitching I was in the back of an open top car on the German highway going over 200km/h. I can tell you, it wasn't a nice experience with the wind in your face at only a fraction of the speed of sound. You'll want a suit, or at the very least safety glasses. However, if you want them to wear spandex you could just expand the field out further. It'll accelerate the air caught just in front of it, massively reducing any air resistance. You might want to weaken the field ever so slightly, so the air can still move and fill your lungs though.
For the legs repeatedly getting a jolt from running at a pace not intended by biology? The field again. The shock of a step will be 'absorbed' by telekinesis decelerating the leg along with the shock. Even here it is unequal deceleration that causes problems and the field can help.
Conclusion
You'll add a field that extends slightly from the body. This unconsciously accelerates and decellerates the body at the correct speed. This also applies to catching any shock from stepping. The boundry of the field extends from the body, weakening with distance to allow some physics to happen and reducing most ill effects from the world around him.
Closing notes
This telekinesis power is insane. The speedster can use this to do some insane things. At the speeds they can run the powers are pretty strong, so they can run through concrete walls. There's probably a huge amount of 'hacks' with these powers to pretty much destroy the universe if you're not careful. Mess with physics in such ways and prepare for unintended consequences. Might be a great plot point though.

A telekinetic field like this could in effect also make the speedster invincible against most projectile-weapons, explosions and falling damage.

@Falco no doubt. I think any telekinesis that can get someone safely up to such speeds in so little time would have unintended consequences. Though I've been surprised by some creative answers before that tame such consequences to a degree. Maybe someone will post one here still.

This field/area could be something that needs to be trained. In the beginning you master running in a line, then add complexer crurves and keep up etc. From there you start going faster and faster. Its like muscle memory, more like balance. You cant turn balance on/off, but you do master it. That would fix the issue @falco speaks of :)

Forces aren't implicitly dangerous. Differences in force per unit mass across different parts of your body are dangerous. (Including microscopic parts, like a difference between the forces on different parts of individual cells.) Apply the same ratio of force to mass to every molecule in the body and you won't even feel it.
In real life the only force that can accelerate all masses distributed through your body (and clothes, dental fillings, etc) identically is gravity$^1$. In your story, the only forces that can do that are gravity and telekinesis.
This answer assumes that air resistance is one of the side effects of super-speed that can be ignored.


not counting frame-dependent forces that are really the result of other things accelerating around you, like the Coriolis force, centrifugal force, and Euler force.


Beware your internal organs, especially your brain.
Accelerating your body to the speed of sound in such a short time is the equivalent of getting hit by a large concussive force (ie an explosion or bomb shockwave) which would cause major trauma and injury.
In order to counteract the trauma, your telekinesis abilities would need to focus on many parts of the body to ensure damage is not catastrophic:

Limbs - moving your body or parts of it at any different rate may sever limbs or damage them. You need to ensure all force is applied to all areas of the body equally
Organs - internal organs are actually quite susceptible to damage if moved drastically. For instance, your lungs are filled with air, and if suddenly compressed you would be 'winded'. Any telekinesis abilities would need to ensure proper functioning of internal organs.
Blood - even just being upside down causes blood to behave differently in our bodies. Pushing your body in one direction drastically would cause blood pressure to be unevenly distributed - in particular the brain which is very susceptible to this and brown outs and black outs are common with many fighter pilots undergoing manoeuvres that cause pressure differences in the brain.
The Brain - Symptoms of concussion is caused by the brain moving such that it impacts the side of the skull. The brain is a fragile object, and any deformation may cause brain damage or rupturing of any of the blood vessels within the brain. Your telekinesis ability would need to ensure the brain is in shape, no vessels torn, and does not impact the side of the skull.

Accompanying the superpower could be physical mitigation strategies, such as wearing Air Force G-Suits (using pressure to keep everything tight and moving together). This could be a good 'superpower' uniform for your character.
But regardless your superpower character needs an in-depth knowledge of anatomy and the ability to carefully tailor forces within their body for each organ, especially their brain. That in itself seems to be a superpower on its own.

When accelerating there is generally something that moves only a part of your body. The rest of your body, including your delicate internals, kind of lags behind. Everything gets pushed or pulled by other parts of your body, and this causes internal stresses or buildup of pressure.
If you can avoid those local stresses, you would not feel the movement/forces at all.
There are a few solutions for this:

If the telekinesis is based on "force", the hero needs to meticulously apply forces proportional to the weight of each particle in his body. (This can be seen from Newton’s Second Law F = m * a when keeping the acceleration constant)
The telekinesis works like a warp drive, where it doesn't move the particles, but it moves the (fabric of) space that contains those particles, leaving the particles inside the "warp bubble" stationary.

It could destroy space in front of the body and create new space behind the body. But this seems rather powerful.
Or more smoothly move space around your body.



Notice that in the warp bubble case, the effect felt by the outside world is in the opposite direction, but only in the immediate vicinity of your body. Particles that happen to be inside the piece of space-fabric being moved, will jump (or quickly move) behind you before continuing in the same direction as they were before. People trying to touch you would feel the same stresses as if their hand was propelled backwards instead of being dragged with you.

I do not know what the maximum speed of a speedster is desirable for you. But if he can only move in a straight line at lightning speed, then you can limit the speedster's speed to below mach one.
This should not significantly reduce the level of your character's abilities, but he, in turn, will not receive a strong load from acceleration and movement speed. For example, a maximum of 60 meters per second. This way your character will be safe, but he will still be acceptably fast.
